# iterate through list of list and collect elements to a string

Tags: scala, case-class

I have a nested list structure and I want to iterate through the list and print the custom string version of it

```
 trait Value{
          def myString:String
        }

  case class Student(value: String) extends Value{
    override def myString: String = s"Student =$value"
  }
  case class Employee(value: Double) extends Value{
    override def myString: String = s"Employee =$value"
  }
  case class Department(value: Int) extends Value{
    override def myString: String = s"Dept =$value"
  }

  case class Grp (elements: List[Value] = Nil) extends Value {
    def add (value: Value): Grp = Grp(this.elements ++ List(value))
    override def myString: String = ""
  }

  val group= Grp()
    .add(Student("abc"))
    .add(Employee(100.20))
    .add( Department(10))
    .add( Grp().add( Student("xyz"))) // nested group`e
    .add( Grp().add( Employee("def")))
```

I want to have the string representation of the `group` .How to iterate through the `group` to call `myString` method

**Updated**

Output

```
Student = abc
Employee = 100.20
Department =10
Student =xyz
Employee= def
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
group.elements.map(_.value.myString).mkString("\n")
```

**Note**

Your `Grp` class is inherits from `Value`, so the above solution should actually be the value of `myString` in your group `Grp` class. Then to get a string representation of `Grp`, you simply call `group.myString`.

---

To clarify,

```
case class Grp (elements: List[Value] = Nil) extends Value {
    def add (value: Value): Grp = Grp(this.elements ++ List(value))
    override def myString: String = elements match {
        case e::rest => elements.map(_.myString).mkString("\n")
        case _ => ""
    }
}
```

Now just do `groups.myString` to get the string

Comment: it doesnt print the nested group value `Student("xyz")`

Comment: sry my bad I need to update my question.The actual use case is a bit different

Comment: As I was saying in the note, you need to override and specify a value for `myString` in the `Grp` class. That way, the conversion will recursively convert all nested `Grps` to string

Comment: I have updated the question.The `Element ` case class is not there,so map wont work as I am not storing as key value pair

Comment: @coder25, The `Elements` class had nothing to do with the solution. See my updated answer

Comment: `groups.myString` gives empty string and I want to print the value in nested group `Student("xyz")` using its `myString` only

Comment: @coder25, Ok I fixed the code. It was just mismatching on match expression

Comment: @coder25, it matches a non empty list. The one I had before matches an empty list. So as long as your list contains atleast one value, it will always match